# How to target this dash html element inside the double quotes using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, quotes

I am having a hard time targeting this dash because I wanted to change it into |.
Check this screenshot please:
[image]

How to target that line and replace it with |?

This is the code that I am using but it does not work. Please help.

`$( ".fusion-price-rating .price:contains('–') .woocommerce-Price-amount::after" ).text('|');`

Comment: Not sure whether it makes difference but just try `$(".fusion-price-rating .price:contains(' - ') .woocommerce-Price-amount::after" ).text('|');` Notice the space in your string.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help but It still does not work. it says:
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .fusion-price-rating .price:contains(' - ') .woocommerce-Price-amount::after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function:

```
$(".woocommerce-Price-amount").text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace("-", "|"); 
});
```

Comment: sorry, my bad again. I used a short dash - instead of a long dash –. It works now! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var el = $(".fusion-price-rating .price:contains('–')");
el.html(el.html().replace('-', '|'));
```

Comment: I think , this will replace whole html content to `|` inside `price` class ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am not trying to happen. I just want to replace the dash -, not the whole HTML content.

This is what it looks like on my site $2.70 – $33.00.

I just want it to be like this one: $2.70 | $33.00